# Ordered lattice point enumeration

Tags: sorting, enumeration, mathematical-lattices

**Setup:** Let ei be an orthogonal basis for n-dimensional Euclidean space, but suppose that ei has irrational (L1) norm. Let L be the set of points obtained by taking linear combinations of the ei with coefficients in the natural numbers (including zero). Now order the points in L first by their L1-norm and then lexicographically.

**Question:** Is there an efficient algorithm for producing the points in L in increasing order up to some pre-defined bound? Note that I do not want to produce the points and then sort them, rather I want to walk the lattice in order.

**Observation:** This is easy to do if the ei are an orthonormal basis. For instance, this problem is solved [here](http://en.literateprograms.org/Generating_all_integer_lattice_points_%28Python%29#In_order_of_Manhattan_distance). In principle something similar would work here, however determining the radii to iterate over is almost as hard as solving the enumeration problem, so it isn't very useful.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

Let L₁ and L₂ be lists of vectors, where L₁ is the list of visited/processed lattice vectors and L₂ is a list of lists of vectors that will be visited next.

1. Set L₁={ } and L₂ = {[0]}, where 0 is the zero-vector.
2. Let v be the smallest vector of the first list in L₂.
3. Visit/process the vector v.
4. Add the list L={v+e₁,...,v+e<sub>n</sub>} to L₂, such that the lists are sorted by their smallest element. Only generate v+e<sub>i</sub> as long as its norm is smaller than your predefined bound.
5. Insert v at the end of L₁ and remove it from the front of the first list L₂.
6. If the first list is now empty, remove it from L₂. If not, move it to the correct place.
7. If L₂ is not empty, goto 2.

This algorithm requires the e<sub>i</sub> to be sorted by their norm from small to big.

This algorithm adds at most n vectors to L₂ per round. Let B your predefined upper bound, then there are at most n<sup>k</sup>-1 vectors you are going to visit, where k = 1+B/||e₁||. The first ca. n<sup>k'</sup> rounds, the list will be of size n, where k' = B/||e<sub>n</sub>||. So in total you have to store less than N = n<sup>k'</sup> + (n<sup>k</sup>-1)/(n<sup>k'+1</sup>) lists. you can generate a new list in O(n) and add place it in L₂ in O(log N) (binary search the correct place and link insert it there).

So the overall complexity would be something like O(N⋅n⋅log N), but notice that N is about the number of vectors you are looking for.

Notice: most likely there is a faster algorithm, but this is something you can try.